# Para qué sirve el operador :: en C#?

Tags: c#, .net

Quisiera salir de la duda de para qué y cuando utilizar el operador :: en C#, he visto ejemplos como este

```
namespace MyCompany.MyProduct.System
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main() => global::System.Console.WriteLine("Using global alias");
    }

    class Console
    {
        string Suggestion => "Consider renaming this class";
    }
}
```

Pero por más que intento entenderlo no he podido saber como usarlo y para qué se usa ;-;
¿alguien podría ayudarme ?

Comment: https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/operators/namespace-alias-qualifier

Answer (score 1):

EL `::` Se llama Operador de resolución de alcance y se usa para dar a un elemento como una clase o función un nombre único y totalmente calificado en todo el programa.

Imagine que define dos clases A y B y ambas tienen una función que toma cero parámetros y se llama go (). Ambas clases tienen implementaciones diferentes de go () pero ambas son útiles. Sin resolución de alcance, cuando escribe definiciones de las funciones go (), el compilador las verá a ambas y no sabría cuál está asociada con la clase A y cuál está asociada con la clase B.

Hay casos en los que es necesario el nombre completo de una función, como en los casos de anulación de un método de clase. Muchas veces desea llamar a la implementación de la clase base de un método de clase dentro de su anulación de ese método. En tales casos, está combinando efectivamente la funcionalidad de las clases base y derivada o confiando en la implementación base si su implementación derivada no es relevante en contexto en el momento en que se llama.

Imagine:

```
class A { 
public: 
virtual void go(); 
}; 
class B : public A { 
virtual void go() override; 
}; 
void B::go() { 
if ( preferAGo() ) { 
A::go(); 
} else { 
// B implementation of go 
} 
}
```

Otros casos de uso de la resolución de alcance son cuando las clases, enumeraciones, constantes, etc. aparecen dentro de un espacio de nombres. Los espacios de nombres se usan con frecuencia en las bibliotecas porque es posible que los usuarios de las bibliotecas tengan un código existente con el mismo nombre que la biblioteca. El compilador no sabrá la diferencia entre ellos, por lo que todas las construcciones de la biblioteca se definen en un espacio de nombres.

Para utilizar un tipo o entidad en un espacio de nombres, los usuarios pueden referirse a ese tipo utilizando el operador de resolución de alcance y espacio de nombres.

```
std::cout << “Hello World!!”;
```

O pueden definir que cualquier referencia de funciones u objetos debe estar en el siguiente espacio de nombres y, por lo tanto, no necesitará anteponer el espacio de nombres cada vez que lo usen.

```
using namespace std; 
cout << “Hello World!!”;
```

Espero que te sea útil!

Comment: Entiendo que estas respondiendo sobre C++? La pregunta del  op es sobre C#